# Akka-streams - How to take the materialized value of source which is flatMapConcatenated in to another source?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am trying to create a Source[Out,Mat] from a Future[Source[Out,Mat]] and was using the built-in source.fromFuture for that in combination with flatMapConcat. However when using fromFuture the source has a materialized value of NotUsed. When flatMapConcatenating the actual source, the materialized value keeps being notUsed.

Is it possible to take the materialized value of a source which is used inside the flatMapConcat?

The code looks as follows:

```
def sourceFromFutureSource[Out,Mat](futureSource: Future[Source[Out,Mat]]): Source[Out, Mat] = {
Source.fromFuture(futureSource)
  .flatMapConcat(identity)
}
```

Comment: I tried looking for a way to solve your problem but I don't think it is possible to retain the original `Mat` type.  Is it really not possible for you to just use the future?  E.g. `futureSource foreach { src => ... }`

Comment: Akka 2.5 has introduced [Source.fromFutureSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666637/akka-streams-how-to-take-the-materialized-value-of-source-which-is-flatmapconc) which keep the materialized value from the asynchronous `Source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Akka 2.5.1 it is possible to use [Source.fromFutureSource](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.3/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html). Now you can do `Source.fromFutureSource(futureSource)`.

Comment: I think you mean Akka 2.5.1. This indeed is exactly what I was looking for!